# ¿Son equivalentes "quedarse tan ancho" y "quedarse tan pancho"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, modismos, expresiones

En España se usan con frecuencia las expresiones **quedarse tan ancho** y **quedarse tan pancho**:

> - A Juan le dijeron que vigilara el fuego, pero se le quemó la
>   tortilla. Lo bueno es que se *quedó tan ancho*.
>
> - Fíjate en ese señor de allí: acaba de tirar un papel en el suelo y
>   se ha *quedado tan pancho*.

Como veis, en ambos casos nos referimos a ejecutar una acción (o no acción) sin que nos importe demasiado la consecuencia de ella (o de su omisión). O al menos así las entiendo yo.

Mirando en el diccionario veo que puden tener cierta diferencia, en cuanto a que *quedarse tan ancho* podría implicar cierto regodeo, mientras que *quedarse tan pancho* sería más bien despreocupación:

> **[ancho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2XUmTEA)**
>
> 7. adj. Orgulloso, envanecido, ufano. *Soltó un disparate y se quedó tan ancho. Qué ancho está con su ordenador nuevo.*
>
> **[pancho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Rdrqca0%7CRduNq6I)<sup>1</sup>, cha**
>
> Del lat. pantex, -ĭcis 'panza'.
>
> 1. adj. Tranquilo, inalterado.

La pregunta que me surge es: ¿son ambas expresiones equivalentes? ¿tiene uno alguna connotación diferente? ¿se usan en más zonas además de España?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por aquí (Andalucía) se conocen las dos expresiones, y por mi experiencia puedo decir que tienen exactamente el sentido que indica el DRAE, tal y como muestras. Por tanto, no son equivalentes. La expresión `quedarse tan pancho` indica eso, tranquilidad, sosiego, mientras que `quedarse tan ancho` indica además un cierto enorgullecimiento del que la otra expresión carece.

En el ejemplo

> Fíjate en ese señor de allí: acaba de tirar un papel en el suelo y se ha quedado tan pancho.

no hay enorgullecimiento, simplemente que ha tirado el papel sin remordimientos, tan tranquilo. En los otros ejemplos sí hay envanecimiento: por el ordenador nuevo, por creer haber soltado una gracia en vez de un disparate, etc. De hecho, en primer ejemplo, el de la tortilla, yo usaría la versión de *pancho*.

Otra cosa es que por la similitud fonética (y semántica hasta cierto punto) la gente las use indistintamente...

Comment: Pues otra cosa que aprendí hoy. Siempre pensé que significaban lo mismo, pero investigando para preguntarlo y especialmente con tu respuesta me di cuenta de que no, son diferentes. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui ¡Un placer!